# A generic error occurred in GDI+ asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, image, c#-4.0, file-upload, base64

I need to save base64string to image in local path. The following are the code I used.

```
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(hdnBase64.Value.Split(',')[1]);

        System.Drawing.Image image;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
            image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

            //image.Save("C:\\test.png"); 
        }

        string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Temp"), filename + ".png");
        image.Save(path);
        imgBrowse.Attributes.Add("src", path);
```

hdnBase64 is a hiddenfield which contain base64 image. while executing I got the generic error. please help me out to solve this problem!

Thanks in advance,
Ganesh M

Comment: Try the overloaded constructor of `MemoryStream` as

    `MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the Save(path) call in the using section. 
You've created the image from a MemoryStream object, which is automatically disposed once you exit from the using block.

```
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(hdnBase64.Value.Split(',')[1]);

    System.Drawing.Image image;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Temp"), filename + ".png");
        image.Save(path);
    }
    imgBrowse.Attributes.Add("src", path);
```